# Windows 10 upgrade kills grub

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

At first, I had Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside with Windows 7 Professional. I was on windows 7 and I upgraded to windows 10. During the installation, It had to restart. What happened when I restarted was that it said
GRUB Loading. 
Error: no such partition. 
Entering rescue mode... 
grub rescue>
I do not know any of the commands. Can someone help me please