# Windows 10 update removed boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I have been running Ubuntu alongside windows 10, but a recent update removed the grub loader.

I tried using Boot Repair as suggest by this post:
[grub rescue> during windows 10 update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/657575/grub-rescue-during-windows-10-update)

But it's repair made things worse. Now on startup I get the message: BOOTMGR missing.

I have tried fiddling with Bootrec /RebuildBcd as suggested here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2622803

but I get nowhere and I don't know what I'm doing. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the Boot Repair's report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/13637524/

Update: Working from a live Ubuntu CD I can't seem to mount my Ubuntu partition because it no longer has a filesystem?

Comment: While working with live Ubuntu CD, what happens when you try to mount your Ubuntu partition? Take a screenshot of error or copy and paste it here!

Answer (score 1):

While I'm nowhere near as experienced with Ubuntu as the earlier answerer, I would advise you not to do anything irreversible.

My guess is that your Ubuntu system is still present, so try to reinstall without reformatting.

Your paste bin report shows Linux partitions to be present, and we have no reason to think that the Windows update would have destroyed it. I'm thinking is just messed up grub.

Take it slowly, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Ubuntu system installed.
(no Linux ext file system on the disk)
So, you will have to reinstall Ubuntu.

Boot from Ubuntu install media - open GParted.
Delete the partition sda4 and the partition sda5.
Create an extended partition from the free space.

Create a new logical partition under the extended partition and format it with file system ext4.
Create another new logical partition under the extended partition and format it with linux-swap.

Start the Ubuntu installer and when asked what to do, choose Something else.
Select the ext4 partition you had created before and set / (root) as mount point.