# Grub issue with dual os?

Tags: 14.04, windows-10

I had two os in my lappy, one is windows 7, second one is ubuntu14.04. Now my system already download the windows 10.

I read it some where long time ago.
If i will update the windows, it will remove my grub which is providing me options which os i want to use.

And right now i don't want to mess with os is there any way to get windows 10 without loosing ubuntu. or in simple words how to save gurb?

Answer (score 1):

if you upgrade your window then your Ubuntu will not loose it will be there but it may be window overwrite your Ubuntu grub that you can reinstall grub without loosing Ubuntu  by `Boot from the live CD` [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) or `boot Repair` [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or any other method . some time window not overwrite grub but it show window 7 instead of window 10 that you can change from grub file and update grub 
for change in grub file use bellow command after upgrading that will reflect change in grub file

```
update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a linux liveUsb and boot on it, once booted :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Follow the instructions and reboot

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 on a dual boot. I didn't loose any of the OSes or GRUB. There should be no problems with the upgrade http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-upgrade-a-dual-boot-installation-of-windows/d7ca80ce-96b0-4f0a-9a8e-4038ded592b2
However, I had some problems but all were solvable
[windows 10 and ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654316/windows-10-and-ubuntu-dual-boot/654994#654994)